# float parse are different on Windows 7 or 8?

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-8

I tested my program on Windows 7 today. It did not work, i found the error.

Following situation:

I converted a string into a float.
Windows 8: `float.Parse (String.Replace(".", ","))`

But on Windows 7, I have to do the opposite directly to not have a crash.

Windows 7: `float.Parse(String.Replace (",", "."))`

> Windows 7 float = 50.00
>
> Windows 8 float = 50,50

Why is that?

Do you know good ways to solve this?

Comment: Is one of your machines is being used by a user from Europe? Floats are formatted / parsed by default using the conventions of the user's location.

Comment: Use `float.Parse("", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to avoid os current culture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nothing to do with Windows 7 or 8 but your regional/localization settings.  If you want to be able to always parse with '.' you can specify `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the second argument to most parsing functions.